# How to sum all elements of a list of characters with mutate?

Tags: r, list, loops, dplyr

I have a `data frame` in R with a variable `a` which has a list of characters in it.
The list is like: `list('5', '7', '9')`

When I iterate by using a `for` loop, I'm able to calculate it:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$a[i] <- sum(as.numeric(unlist(df$a[i])))
}
```

But, when I try that by using `mutate`, it returns `NA`.

```
df %>% mutate(
  c <- sum(as.numeric(unlist(a)))
)
```

What is the problem with this code, and what should I do?

Comment: It should be `c = `. Also, `unlist` will recursively do the unlisting.  May be `df %>% mutate(c = map_dbl(a, ~ sum(as.numeric(.x))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a `list` of elements, we can loop using `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     mutate(c = map_dbl(a, ~ sum(as.numeric(.x))))
```

Comment: Thank you! I find that simpler and faster than using loop for.